# Manual patching of an Ubuntu bug (sydtemd)

Tags: systemd

In a project we run into a [known bug](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/3374) with systemd/udevd.

Now, there are yet no official patches for that we could install using package management.

What would be the most pragmatic way to manually replace the systemd package with a custom patch containing a fix?

---

Will try so far the [HACKING](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/HACKING) file in systemd GitHub.

Comment: What is the bug you are running into? The link refers to the HACKING file.

Comment: there is also the link to the bug; the question is not about the bug  itself

Comment: You had two links with reference `[1]` in your post, thus they were pointing to the same URI. I fixed it for you. Even though the question is not about the bug itself, it might help people come up with pragmatic ways to get around your issue.